# Jasper Report Html Exporter Chart not displayed

Tags: java, grails, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Report 6.3.0. I have tried to find similar issue on stackoverflow, but none of those answer fix the issue.

I am having a chart in jasper report and a Java web application on Grails framework exporting to HTML format. Report exported perfectly fine. Issue I am facing is when report displayed on browser. Exported report on file system looks good, but when I show it on browser via web application chart image looks broken, image does not resolve.

**Servlet Mapping:**

```
'servlet' {
    'servlet-name'('ImageServlet')
    'servlet-class'('net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet')
}
'servlet-mapping' {
    'servlet-name'('ImageServlet')
    'url-pattern'('/images')
}
```

**Java Exporter Code:**

```
AbstractHtmlExporter<HtmlReportConfiguration,HtmlExporterConfiguration> exporter = new HtmlExporter();
SimpleHtmlExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(result);

WebHtmlResourceHandler htmlResourceHandler = new WebHtmlResourceHandler(imageFileDir.getName() + "/images?image={0}");

exporterOutput.setImageHandler(htmlResourceHandler);

exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
```

I think that I am making some mistake, but don't know where. The reason I think I am making some mistake is that on checking report html code on browser (developer tool), I see image url as `report.html_files/img_0_0_1.png`

Let me know in case more information required.

Comment: Did you check the source code of html page? Are links to images valid?

Comment: `The reason I think I am making some mistake is that on checking report html code on browser (developer tool), I see image url as report.html_files/img_0_0_1.png` - Maybe you should delete the question or post the solution as an answer

Comment: As we have set ImageHandler, it should not have image path as `report.html_files/img_0_0_1.png`. I am not getting why image are not resolved, as there is image in file system and have set servlet mapping path for ImageServlet.

Comment: @AlexK `Did you check the source code of html page? Are links to images valid?`. Yes, links in HTML page are valid. It is having relative path to chart image.